# How do I select last message for each conversation?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

Here is how my database looks like:

table: `conversations`

```
+----+--------+--------+
| id | user_1 | user_2 |
+----+--------+--------+
| 1  | 1      | 2      |
| 2  | 2      | 3      |
| 3  | 1      | 3      |
+----+--------+--------+
```

table: `messages`

```
+----+--------------+------+
| id | conversation | text |
+----+--------------+------+
| 1  | 1            | hej  |
| 2  | 1            | test |
| 3  | 2            | doh  |
| 4  | 2            | hi   |
| 5  | 3            | :)   |
| 6  | 3            | :D   |
+----+--------------+------+
```

Then when I run the followin query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM `messages`
INNER JOIN `conversations`
    ON `conversations`.`id` = `messages`.`convesations`
GROUP BY `conversations`.`id`
ORDER BY `messages`.`id` DESC
```

Then I get those out from `messages`:

```
+----+--------------+------+
| id | conversation | text |
+----+--------------+------+
| 1  | 1            | hej  |
| 3  | 2            | doh  |
| 5  | 3            | :)   |
+----+--------------+------+
```

But, is it somehow possible to do so that I will get the messages with the highest `messages.id` from that group, instead of the lowest?

EDIT: Here is the output I want from `messages`:

```
+----+--------------+------+
| id | conversation | text |
+----+--------------+------+
| 2  | 1            | test |
| 4  | 2            | hi   |
| 6  | 3            | :D   |
+----+--------------+------+
```

As those are the `messages` in same `conversation` with the highest `id`.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Maybe if you describe your desired output.

Comment: @DanBracuk, I have added my desire ouput to the question.

Comment: It's a pure coincidence that you get the first `id` for each conversation. `MySQL` does allow selecting ungrouped expressions, but you should not make any assumptions on what record within the group would they belong to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    conversations c
JOIN    messages m
ON      m.id =
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    messages mi
        WHERE   mi.conversation = c.id
        ORDER BY
                mi.conversation DESC, mi.id DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

Create an index on `messages (conversation, id)` for this to work fast.

Answer (score 4):

You simply need to use nested query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Messages 
WHERE ID IN(
            SELECT Max(m.ID) FROM Messages m
            INNER JOIN conversations c
                    ON c.id = m.conversation
              GROUP BY m.conversation
           );
```

Output:

```
| ID | CONVERSATION | TEXT |
----------------------------
|  2 |            1 | test |
|  4 |            2 |   hi |
|  6 |            3 |   :D |
```

If you want data from both tables try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Messages m
    JOIN conversations c
      ON c.id = m.conversation
WHERE m.ID IN (
                 SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Messages 
                 GROUP BY conversation
              )
GROUP BY m.conversation;
```

Output:

```
| ID | CONVERSATION | TEXT | USER_1 | USER_2 |
----------------------------------------------
|  2 |            1 | test |      1 |      2 |
|  4 |            2 |   hi |      2 |      3 |
|  6 |            3 |   :D |      1 |      3 |
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49185/13)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have an incorrect table join:

```
SELECT *
FROM `messages`
INNER JOIN `conversations`
    ON `conversations`.`id` = `messages`.`conversation`
GROUP BY `conversations`.`id`
ORDER BY `messages`.`id` DESC
```

### Edit

You can try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `messages`
WHERE `messages`.`id` IN (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM messages
    GROUP BY conversation
)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I rewrote it, as my own query is much bigger, due to many other joins. Thanks and have changed my query in the question.

Comment: You might want to fix up that typo in the new query!  :)

Comment: I've given a nice and simple revised query that will give the result you're after.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You are making your Join on the wrong column. 'Id' in Conversation cannot be equal to 'Id' in messages.

I thin, 'Conversation' in table messsages is 'id_conversation' right?

So, if I understood well :

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
INNER JOIN conversations
    ON conversations.id = messages.conversation
GROUP BY conversations.id
ORDER BY messages.id DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of different approaches:

This approach relies on known but undocumented behaviour within MySQL, where the unaggregated, ungrouped values returned in a grouped query are the first in the sort order - it's fast, but should not be viewed as reliable:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM messages 
ORDER BY conversation, id desc) a
GROUP BY conversation
```

Alternatively, an approach that should always be reliable:

```
SELECT m.*, c.user_1, c.user_2 FROM messages m
 JOIN (select conversation, max(id) max_id from messages group by conversation) l
   ON m.id = l.max_id
 JOIN conversations c
   ON c.id = m.conversation
GROUP BY conversation
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a890/7).

Comment: The first query would probably work in current versions of `MySQL` but  it's purely implementation dependent and not specified in the docs. You should not rely on this.

Comment: @Quassnoi: I agree - I have added a brief explanation to my answer.